# removing sentences contained in a list if they are located at the end of a text

Tags: python, nlp, data-cleaning

I am cleaning companies names in dataframe rows, and want to remove places contained in a list, only if they appeared at the end of the name and it is not followed by "of" or "in".
I am able to do this in STATA but it takes ages to process big data.
So, I would like to remove Liverpool from "KFC liverpool" but not from "Taxis in Liverpool"

So far, I figured something like this (did not get to the "of" or "in" part yet):

```
places = ["liverpool", "west essex", "bristol", "sanders park"]

class remove_cities:

    def __init__(self, text, places_list):
        self.text = text
        self.places_list= places_list

    def remove_cities(self):
        for plac in self.places_list:
            self.text = self.text.removesuffix(plac)           
        return self

    def identify_sentences(self):
        self = self.remove_cities()
        return self.text
   
places_list = places_all
tqdm.pandas(desc="Text Preprocessing")
clean_companyname_df = clean_companyname_df[["company_clean"]].progress_applymap(
    lambda x: remove_cities(x, places_list=places_list).identify_sentences()
)
```

But I get the error: **TypeError: removesuffix() argument must be str, not list**

I do not want to convert the text into a string since cities can be such as "West Essex", and I do not want to eliminate the word "west" from the end of the company name.
**Can somebody help me?**

Answer (score 0):

Since your case is quite specific, I don't think you can directly clean the company names with some panda functions.

First analyse the different cases :

#### Cases

Case 1 : `company_name` is a single word.
Simply return `company_name`.

Case 2 : `company_name` ends with "west essex" or "sanders park".

- Case 2.1 : "of" or "in" occur just before "west essex" or "sanders park".

  - Return `company_name` as it is.
- Case 2.2 : "of" or "in" does not occur just before "west essex" or "sanders park".

  - Remove "west essex" or "sanders park" from `company_name`.

Case 3 : `company_name` ends with "liverpool" or "bristol"

- Case 3.1 : "of" or "in" occur just before "liverpool" or "bristol".

  - Return `company_name` as it is.
- Case 3.2 : "of" or "in" does not occur just before "liverpool" or "bristol".

  - Remove "liverpool" or "bristol"  from `company_name`.

Then write the code :

```py
places = ["liverpool", "west essex", "bristol", "sanders park"]


def FilterCompanyName(company_name):

    # convert company_name to a list of words
    words = company_name.split()
    # print(words)
    if len(words) == 1:  # make no change if company name is a single word
        return company_name

    last_word = words[-1]
    second_last_word = words[-2]  # word before last word
    last_two_words = second_last_word.lower() + " " + last_word.lower()

    # deal with case where last_two_words are "west essex" or "sanders park"
    if last_two_words in places:

        if len(words) == 2:  # company name is "west essex" or "sanders park"
            return company_name

        third_last_word = words[-3]  # word before second_last_word
        if third_last_word.lower() == "in" or third_last_word.lower() == "of":
            return company_name

        # deal with case where last_two_words are "west essex" or
        # "sanders park" and
        # third_last_word is "in" or "of"
        words.remove(last_word)
        words.remove(second_last_word)
        return ' '.join(words)

    # deal with case where last word is "liverpool" or "bristol"
    if last_word in places:
        if (second_last_word.lower() == "in" or
                second_last_word.lower() == "of"):
            return company_name
        words.remove(last_word)
    return ' '.join(words)


test_cases = ["KFC liverpool",
              "Taxis in Liverpool",
              "West Essex",
              "The best in west essex",
              "LIVERPOOL",
              "big bristol forever",
              "big bristol",
              "KFC west essex",
              "KFC of Sanders Park"]

for test_case_number in range(0, len(test_cases)):
    test = test_cases[test_case_number]
    print("Test case " + str(test_case_number) + ": " + test +
          " -> " + FilterCompanyName(test)+"\n")
```

Output :

```
Test case 0: KFC liverpool -> KFC

Test case 1: Taxis in Liverpool -> Taxis in Liverpool

Test case 2: West Essex -> West Essex

Test case 3: The best in west essex -> The best in west essex

Test case 4: LIVERPOOL -> LIVERPOOL

Test case 5: big bristol forever -> big bristol forever

Test case 6: big bristol -> big

Test case 7: KFC west essex -> KFC

Test case 8: KFC of Sanders Park -> KFC of Sanders Park
```

You will have to integrate my function with your code.